# sfc /scannow Unable to Repair Corrupt Component Store

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1511

Since updating my laptop with the Windows 10 November update, a component of my Component Store seems to have gone corrupt that neither using the media utility to reinstall the update nor running `sfc /scannow`  is able to resolve. Whenever I execute the `sfc /scannow` command, I get the following error:

```
Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some
of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For
example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not
supported in offline servicing scenarios.
```

I do not know how to read the log file, and it is extremely large (~100,000 lines since I've run it so much), so I do not want to put the entire thing on Pastebin. If someone knows what to look for or what I should pull from the log to post, I can do so.

Comment: Delete the log file first. Run sfc again. Search for the word "failed" in the log file. Also see if you have any "CSI Payload Corrupt" entries there.

Comment: Searching for "failed" and "CSI Payload Corrupt" did not return anything. I've uploaded a copy of the log file to Dropbox since Chrome does not seem to appreciate me trying to copy the entire text from the log file in to Pastebin. https://www.dropbox.com/s/p4dfyordknwf5aj/CBS.log?dl=0

Comment: Hm... That's strange. I don't see anything in your log file that would justify "found corrupt files but was unable to fix" message from sfc. Entries like "duplicate ownership..." are rather innocent - we all have this. The rest are "directory not owned...", which are innocent as well. All your log entries are "Info" entries, not "Error" entries, which means that there's noting out of ordinary in your CBS.log.

Comment: @AnT So the duplicate ownership issue should not be causing the "corrupt file" message in the console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 32Bit `OpenCL.dll` is damaged:

> Cannot repair member file [l:10]"opencl.dll" of
>   microsoft-windows-RemoteFX-clientVM-RemoteFXWDDMDriver-WOW64-C,
>   version 10.0.10586.0, arch Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, pkt {l:8
>   b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch

Since Windows 8, you can use the a new [DISM command to repair corrupted files](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx):

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

This will download the clean file from Microsoft server.

If this fails, [download the Version 1511 ISO](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench), mount the ISO into a virtual DVD drive and run this command:

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:wim:D:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess
```

*(where D: is your mounted Win10 ISO)*

Comment: The DISM command just outputs the following: `Error: 0x800f081f

The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log` DISM Log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qczd6ash8n007yx/dism.log?dl=0

Comment: @DavidB -  The reason DISM couldn't repair the file is because it isn't in the WInSxS folder.  This is because you installed the update, and the folder, was adjusted and any irrelevant packages were removed.  In other words unless you need this feature you can ignore it.  The actual package isn't even compatible with Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound Can I just browse to the location of the file and delete it then?

Comment: It is worth a try.  Since the file is corrupt you really don't have anything to lose.  If `RemoteFX` at any point was installed on your system you should just uninstall it.  If you have any applications that require `OpenCL` you should install them again.

Comment: @DavidB I added a other solution. Also try this

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you, although I was able to resolve the issue by copying the corrupt DLL file from my mom's computer to my computer. Running `sfc /scannow` after putting the file in place shows no integrity violations.

Comment: Good solution - http://serverfault.com/a/741491/288323

Comment: Agree with @23W that http://serverfault.com/a/741491/288323 is good solution ... but also make sure you use the correct ISO source as recommended there by 23W (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench) on another (lower-rated) answer to that question. My newest MSDN image gave the infamous 0x800f081f error, but correct ISO source worked. Insufficient rep to comment over there :-(