# Windows 10 corrupt files issue error 0x800f081f

Tags: windows-10, file-corruption, dism, windows-10-v1511, sfc

After running `sfc /scannow` in cmd, I get the error message : "

> Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix
>   some of them."

Looking at the details in the log, this set of four lines kept appearing.

> 2015-12-12 11:58:26, Info                  CSI    00003d48 [SR] Cannot
>   repair member file [l:10]"opencl.dll" of
>   microsoft-windows-RemoteFX-clientVM-RemoteFXWDDMDriver-WOW64-C,
>   version 10.0.10586.0, arch Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, pkt {l:8
>   b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch
>
> 2015-12-12 11:58:27, Info                  CSI    00003d52 [SR] Cannot
>   repair member file [l:10]"opencl.dll" of
>   microsoft-windows-RemoteFX-clientVM-RemoteFXWDDMDriver-WOW64-C,
>   version 10.0.10586.0, arch Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, pkt {l:8
>   b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch
>
> 2015-12-12 11:58:27, Info                  CSI    00003d53 [SR] This
>   component was referenced by
>   [l:125]"Microsoft-Windows-RemoteFX-VM-Setup-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0.RemoteFX
>   clientVM and UMTS files and regkeys"
>
> 2015-12-12 11:58:27, Info                  CSI    00003d56 [SR] Could
>   not reproject corrupted file [l:23
>   ml:24]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64"[l:10]"opencl.dll"; source file in
>   store is also corrupted

After running `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth` it returned:

> "The component store is repairable. The operation completed
>   successfully."

The same thing happened with `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth`.
I then tried  `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` but the error message was:

> "Error: 0x800f081f The source files could not be found. Use the
>   "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required
>   to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source
>   location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.
>
> The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log"

I though I would have fixed the problem when I reset my computer just a few days ago because I was getting the same message.
I have a Surface Pro 3 by the way, if that helps.

Comment: See this. http://www.hackaapl.com/how-to-repair-windows-10-issues-windows-update-component-store-corruption-etc/

Comment: RemoteFX is not a critical system function.  OpenCL has many sources, primarily, your display drivers.  These are not even worth repairing outside of the OpenCL error, [many questions here](http://superuser.com/questions/1002516/sfc-scannow-unable-to-repair-corrupt-component-store/1002606#1002606), on how to fix that file.

Comment: have you tried the DISM commands?

Answer (score 1):

The opencl.dll repair issue is strange. The [user Daniel](https://superuser.com/users/364395/daniel) explained how he solved it on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/a/741491):

> 1. Mount the ISO image.
> 2. Create a temporary directory to mount the Windows Image File (WIM).     `mkdir C:\WIM`
> 3. Mount the WIM file.     `Dism /Mount-Wim /WimFile:D:\sources\install.wim /index:1 /MountDir:C:\WIM /ReadOnly`
> 4. Run Dism with the following parameters.     `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:C:\WIM\Windows /LimitAccess`
> 5. When done, unmount the image and delete the folder     `Dism /Unmount-Wim /MountDir:C:\WIM /Discard    rmdir C:\WIM`
> 6. It's mandatory to restart your computer, or SFC and DISM will still show errors.

You need a 10.0.10586 ISO from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench).