# Windows 10 random slow logins

Tags: windows-10

I have the following problem which occurs randomly:

1. I boot my PC
2. It loads up into logon screen quite quick
3. I enter my credentials (I use Windows account, if that makes any difference)
4. Logging in takes more than usual (about 10 seconds).
5. Once it logs in, I can see my wallpaper, icons on desktop, however my taskbar is empty, it has just Start Icon. As seen in following screenshot:

[image: My Windows]

6. I'm not able to do anything until taskbar icons appear
7. If I hover my cursors on taskbar, I see loading Icon.

It doesn't happen too often, but it's hella annoying. What could be potential issues and fixes? I've seen someone having similar issues with [GeForce Experience](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/857772/latest-geforce-experience-slow-windows-startup-bug-fix-/) causing slow boots:

> Seems that in the latest version of GeForce experience there is an
>   issue with one of the services which causes your boot time to be a lot
>   slower. The issue is with the nvstreamsvc which makes windows hang on
>   boot I hope nvidia fixes the issues asap for people that want a fix
>   until nvidia fix this issue themselves look below.

I uninstalled it, but that did not solve my issue.

If any additional information is needed, please leave a comment - I'll add it.

#### Logs from ntbtlog.txt

```
¬´Ą˙˙ 1 20 2016 22:54:32.497
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\hal.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\kd.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\mcupdate_GenuineIntel.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\werkernel.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\CLFS.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tm.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\PSHED.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\BOOTVID.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\cmimcext.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\ntosext.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\CI.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\msrpc.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\FLTMGR.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\ksecdd.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\clipsp.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\Wdf01000.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\WDFLDR.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\acpiex.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\WppRecorder.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\cng.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\ACPI.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\WMILIB.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\WindowsTrustedRT.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\WindowsTrustedRTProxy.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\pcw.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\msisadrv.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\pci.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\vdrvroot.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\pdc.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\CEA.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\partmgr.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\spaceport.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\volmgr.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\volmgrx.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\mountmgr.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\storahci.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\storport.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\EhStorClass.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\fileinfo.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Wof.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\NTFS.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Fs_Rec.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\ndis.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\NETIO.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\ksecpkg.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tcpip.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\fwpkclnt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\wfplwfs.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\aswVmm.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\aswRvrt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\fvevol.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\volsnap.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rdyboost.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\mup.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\hwpolicy.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\disk.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\CLASSPNP.SYS
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\cdrom.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\aswSP.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\aswSnx.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\filecrypt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Null.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Beep.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\BasicDisplay.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\BasicRender.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Npfs.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Msfs.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\tdx.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\netbt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\aswRdr2.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\afd.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\vwififlt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\pacer.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\netbios.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\rdbss.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\csc.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\nsiproxy.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\npsvctrig.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\mssmbios.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \??\C:\Program Files (x86)\UltraISO\drivers\ISODrv64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\gpuenergydrv.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\dfsc.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\ahcache.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\compositebus.inf_amd64_912dfdedc3d2f520\CompositeBus.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\kdnic.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\umbus.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\HDAudBus.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\ucx01000.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\USBXHCI.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\TeeDriverW8x64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\usbehci.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rt640x64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\serial.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\serenum.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\parport.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\intelppm.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\ISCTD64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\NdisVirtualBus.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\swenum.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\LGBusEnum.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\LGJoyXlCore.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rdpbus.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\RzSurroundVAD.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\ksthunk.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\usbhub.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\nvhda64v.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\UsbHub3.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\RTKVHD64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\MBfilt64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\HdAudio.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\usbccgp.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\hidusb.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\LGSHidFilt.Sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\mouhid.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\mouclass.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\kbdhid.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\kbdclass.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rzendpt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rzudd.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\lvuvc64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\usbaudio.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\lvrs64.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\monitor.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\WudfPf.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\WUDFRd.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\luafv.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rdpvideominiport.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\storqosflt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\aswMonFlt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rdpdr.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\bowser.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\mrxsmb.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\mrxsmb20.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\lltdio.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\mslldp.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\rspndr.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\wanarp.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\aswStm.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\HTTP.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\mpsdrv.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \??\C:\Program Files\Logitech Gaming Software\Drivers\LgCoreTemp\lgcoretemp.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\aswHwid.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\mmcss.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\srvnet.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\mrxsmb10.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\Ndu.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\peauth.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\rzpmgrk.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\rzpnk.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tcpipreg.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\WibuKey64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\srv2.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\srv.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tunnel.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\condrv.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \??\C:\Program Files (x86)\TuneUp Utilities 2014\TuneUpUtilitiesDriver64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tunnel.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\LGVirHid.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\lvuvc64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\usbaudio.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\lvrs64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\LGBusEnum.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\LGJoyXlCore.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \??\C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\LNonPnP.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\LGSHidFilt.Sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\LGBusEnum.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\LGJoyXlCore.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \??\C:\Program Files\Logitech Gaming Software\Drivers\LgCoreTemp\lgcoretemp.sys
 1 20 2016 22:59:54.497
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\hal.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\kd.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\mcupdate_GenuineIntel.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\werkernel.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\CLFS.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tm.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\PSHED.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\BOOTVID.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\cmimcext.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\ntosext.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\CI.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\msrpc.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\FLTMGR.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\ksecdd.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\clipsp.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\Wdf01000.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\WDFLDR.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\acpiex.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\WppRecorder.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\cng.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\ACPI.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\WMILIB.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\WindowsTrustedRT.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\WindowsTrustedRTProxy.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\pcw.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\msisadrv.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\pci.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\vdrvroot.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\pdc.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\CEA.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\partmgr.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\spaceport.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\volmgr.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\volmgrx.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\mountmgr.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\storahci.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\storport.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\EhStorClass.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\fileinfo.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Wof.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\NTFS.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Fs_Rec.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\ndis.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\NETIO.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\ksecpkg.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tcpip.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\fwpkclnt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\wfplwfs.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\aswVmm.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\aswRvrt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\fvevol.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\volsnap.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rdyboost.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\mup.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\hwpolicy.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\disk.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\CLASSPNP.SYS
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\cdrom.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\aswSP.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\aswSnx.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\filecrypt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Null.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Beep.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\BasicDisplay.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\BasicRender.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Npfs.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Msfs.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\tdx.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\netbt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\aswRdr2.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\afd.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\vwififlt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\pacer.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\netbios.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\rdbss.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\csc.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\nsiproxy.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\npsvctrig.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\mssmbios.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \??\C:\Program Files (x86)\UltraISO\drivers\ISODrv64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\gpuenergydrv.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\dfsc.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\ahcache.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\compositebus.inf_amd64_912dfdedc3d2f520\CompositeBus.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\kdnic.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\umbus.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\HDAudBus.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\ucx01000.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\USBXHCI.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\TeeDriverW8x64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\usbehci.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rt640x64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\serial.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\serenum.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\parport.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\intelppm.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\ISCTD64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\NdisVirtualBus.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\swenum.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\LGBusEnum.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\LGJoyXlCore.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rdpbus.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\RzSurroundVAD.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\ksthunk.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\usbhub.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\nvhda64v.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\UsbHub3.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\RTKVHD64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\MBfilt64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\HdAudio.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\usbccgp.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\hidusb.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\LGSHidFilt.Sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\mouhid.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\mouclass.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\kbdhid.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\kbdclass.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rzendpt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rzudd.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\lvuvc64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\usbaudio.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\lvrs64.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\monitor.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\WudfPf.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\WUDFRd.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\luafv.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rdpvideominiport.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\storqosflt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\aswMonFlt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rdpdr.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\mslldp.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\bowser.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\mrxsmb.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\mrxsmb20.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\lltdio.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\rspndr.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\aswStm.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\wanarp.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\HTTP.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\mpsdrv.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\aswHwid.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \??\C:\Program Files\Logitech Gaming Software\Drivers\LgCoreTemp\lgcoretemp.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\mrxsmb10.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\Ndu.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\peauth.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\srvnet.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\srv2.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\mmcss.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\rzpmgrk.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\rzpnk.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\WibuKey64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tcpipreg.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\srv.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tunnel.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\condrv.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \??\C:\Program Files (x86)\TuneUp Utilities 2014\TuneUpUtilitiesDriver64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tunnel.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\LGVirHid.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\lvuvc64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\usbaudio.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\lvrs64.sys
```

#### `chkdsk` output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>chkdsk
The type of the file system is NTFS.

WARNING!  /F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...


  459264 file records processed.

File verification completed.


  7540 large file records processed.


  0 bad file records processed.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...


  579342 index entries processed.

Index verification completed.


  0 unindexed files scanned.


  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.


  60040 data files processed.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...


  35062280 USN bytes processed.

Usn Journal verification completed.

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

 124520447 KB total disk space.
  72735212 KB in 304128 files.
    147488 KB in 60041 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    568159 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
  51069588 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
  31130111 total allocation units on disk.
  12767397 allocation units available on disk.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

#### `sfc /scannow` results:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some
of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For
example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not
supported in offline servicing scenarios.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Looking at that file, there's one line constantly repeating:

```
2016-01-20 23:14:59, Info                  CSI    00003e15 [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [l:23 ml:24]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64"\[l:10]"opencl.dll"; source file in store is also corrupted
```

[This article](http://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/29947-sfc-some-corrupt-files-can-not-fixed.html) suggests running these commands in given order:

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
SFC /scannow
```

I'll update if that doesn't work.

Comment: I have the current version of GeForce Experience and do not suffer with this problem.  Since you uninstalled it the possible bug wasn't the source of your problems.  Does this problem happen while logged into Safe Mode?

Comment: @Ramhound I tried uninstall GeForce experience as potential threat, but apparently it wasn't that. In order to tell that, I'd have to boot into Safe Mode and expect my system to hang up the same way as it does now (which doesn't happen always - it's random). Perhaps there's a way to enable boot logging, so if something hangs up, I could post its' content here?

Comment: You can indeed enable boot logging.  You enable it the same way as in previous versions of Windows.  I realize you uninstalled the application in question, just indicating to you, the problem does not exist on my system with the current version installed.  So the actual problem is software unique to your system or hardware unique to your system that is causing I/O wait events.

Comment: Have you ensured all your drivers (ie: chipset, nVidia display drivers, etc.) are up-to-date with the latest version offered directly by the manufacturer?  Have you checked your disk/file-system for corruption (`chkdsk`)?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I've used TuneUp in order to check if my drive C is corrupted and application told there were no issues. My drivers are up to date. I'm currently running `sfc /scannow`. Added results from `chkdsk`

Comment: *A corrupt OpenCL.dll isn't the source of your problems.*

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/1024089/windows-10-corrupt-files-issue-error-0x800f081f) is one of many questions ( around 10 ) that explain how to fix the corrupt file.  If you uninstalled GeForce Experience, that explains the "corrupt" file though, since OpenCL is installed by that program.  It also is the 32-bit version of the file, which wouldn't be used by Windows itself, only 32-bit third-party applications.