# Corrupt Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I've been having problems with Windows 10 parental control features,  that seem 'Buggy' in nature;  so I did a `sfc /scannow`  in the cmd window. When it finished  windows came back with

*Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some nullof them. Details are included in the CBS.Log*

I rebooted the machine and the ran the scan again a few times,  as I'd seen advised in a [similar post](http://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/21106-sfc-finds-corrupt-files-but-unable-fix.html),  but still no joy, now one of the user accounts doesn't boot.

Lucckley I've another admin user setup or I'd be stuffed!

1) Do I need to try and repair windows,  if so how?

2) what precautions do I need to take to make sure I don't get permanent locked out of my machine?  I haven't got any windows  recovery media,  or instalation discs,  as my laptop didn't come with any.

3) can I create recovery media from a corrupt version of Windows?

Windows 10 can boot into an admin account.

Comment: look in the CBS.log if the opencl.dll is corrupted. This happens very often in win10 1511. if yes, fix it with those steps: http://superuser.com/a/1024219/174557

Comment: I can not find any reference to opencl.dll in the CBS text file.

Comment: share the complete CBS folder (compressed as zip on OneDrive), I'll take a look at it

Comment: 'zipped CBS folder Link:' https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-jjILsKfRP3ODR2eWhkYlM1dDA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: or this: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=61BD24E060C48D23!2776&authkey=!AGo_6SAejvmSGbw&ithint=file%2czip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file part of Microsoft Edge can't be repaired via sfc:

> Cannot repair member file
>   [l:106{53}]"**MicrosoftEdgeSquare44x44.scale-125_contrast-white.png**" of
>   Microsoft-Windows-**MicrosoftEdge**, Version = 10.0.10240.16724, pA =
>   amd64, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store,
>   hash mismatch

use the new DISM command `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` which can download the corrupted file from the Microsoft servers.

10.0.10240 also tells me you still use the July 2015 version, tr to upgrade to 1511 (Build 10586) and look if your parental control feature issues are fixed.

Comment: How can I upgrade to 1511, when settings/windows update/ doesn't show any updates?

Comment: do you use the Enterprise LTSB version? If not, have you delayed the upgrade in the Settings app?

Comment: It's Windows 10 Home.  As far as I can see I haven't delayed the upgrade; but looking in the update history,  upgrade to version  1511, 10586,  failed to install.

Comment: try again to update to 1511 and share the folder  **C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\panther**, this includes logs about the upgrade process

Comment: I've tried catalog. update. Microsoft. Com,  but there are so many "update for Windows 10 version 1511 (k.......? )

Comment: What (k......?)  to use?  And how I find out.

Comment: if it is not offered via WU, download the ISO, mount the ISO, run setup and select upgrade(keep everything): https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/software-download/techbench

Comment: I did this and the installation failed, see screenshot, https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=61BD24E060C48D23!3136&authkey=!AECINpT6vMc-tms&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg, i couldn't find the C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\panther folder to give you.

Comment: Error 0xC1900101 - 0x20017 measn you got a BSOD during upgrade: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3107983 **Make sure all that drivers have been updated. 
    Open the Setuperr.log and Setupact.log files under the %windir%\Panther directory, and then locate the problem drivers.
    Update or uninstall the problem driver.**

Comment: setuperr.log empty, and setupact.log says " [DllHost.exe] Not setting autologon since this is an upgrade or the machine is domain-joined." so not sure how to find the correct driver in the device manger.

Comment: update all drivers (GPU, sound, network) and all software to the latest version and try again to upgrade to 1511.